# Maven Surefire with different file sets

Tags: java, testing, maven

I have two kinds of Unit tests (not integration test). Because of some strange behaviour with Spring Security I need to run first all normal tests, and later on the security tests.

I am using Junit (so I can not use any TestNG groups).

So what I have done is specify two sets of includes and excludes rules.

```
<excludes>
   <exclude>**/*SecurityTest.java</exclude>                  
</excludes>
<includes>
   <include>**/*Test.java</include>
   <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
</includes>
```

and

```
<excludes>
</excludes>
<includes>
    <include>**/*SecurityTest.java</include>
</includes>
```

That works if I replace them in my pom by hand so I can have normal or security tests. But of course I want that both kind of tests run in each build.

My first try was to have two complete maven-surefire-plugin configruation. But then maven take only the last of them in account.

My next try was to use two `execution` definitions,  but then surefire seems to ignore the rules at all and run both kind of tests mixed.

**So my general question is how to specify two file sets for maven surefire so that they will be executed each after another? And more specific how to specify two different file sets.**

---

the configuration with executions

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
        <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
        <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea</argLine>   
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>normal-tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*SecurityTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>security-tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*SecurityTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: does each execution run after another (in sequence)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't changed the default surefire execution which is bound to the test phase in the superpom, so it's still running with its default config. The id of that execution is "default-test". You'll either need to override it to unbind it from the test phase or else just use that id for one of your own executions.

Comment: I know this is a bit late but, could you provide a working example / final version of the solution?